# Azure VM auto scale based on alert

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-vm

The scenario is as follows:

- In company premise, there is a network that consists few machines.
- The company has an Azure subscription.
- Requirement:

1. To monitor the company's Network/Machines via Azure
2. If the company resource goes beyond a threshold limit then trigger alerts. Example, network bandwidth consumption, machine CPU/Memory usage, etc.
3. When such alerts occur then spin up new virtual machines or VM scale sets in Azure to handle the load.

The purpose is if the machines in on-prem goes above threshold limit then automatically provision VMs in Azure, as there are only few on-prem machines.

Please guide how to implement these use cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is a little confusing.  You mention machines on premises and using Azure to monitor them.  You can monitor on premises VMs using Azure but then you mention provisioning new Azure VMs via Scale Sets.

I'm not 100% where your workload is but assuming it is in Azure then if you are using VM Scale Sets it's very easy to scale in and out based on resource utilisation.

This can be configured as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-portal

Comment: The purpose is if the machines in on-prem goes above threshold limit then automatically provision VMs in Azure, as there are only few on-prem machines. I hope I cleared your doubt.

Comment: Thanks.  You could script this.  So deploy the Azure monitor agent to your on-premises VMs and configure alert thresholds for CPU/RAM etc.  Then if the thresholds are exceeded fire an alert which triggers an automation runbook to start your  Azure VMs.  You would need some kind of load balancer in front of the VMs in both locations for your traffic to be delivered to the Azure VMs when scaling out.